# Run DispatcherTimer at every exact minute

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

The following dispatcher runs every 1 minute, counting from the time is invoked its ***Start()*** method...but what I actually need is that it *ticks* on every change in the minute component of the system time. Any idea?
This is a windows application (WPF).

```
DispatcherTimer hourTimer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Normal) 
{ 
    Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0) 
};
hourTimer.Tick += (sender,e) => { renderTime(); };
hourTimer.Start();
```

Comment: You can sleep for `DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60 - DateTime.Now.Seconds)` and start the timer then.

Comment: DateTime.UtcNow is faster than DateTime.Now, the timezone math costs a few ms. When you do time duration math you should always try to use UtcNow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get a "metronome quality beat" from any timer that uses a single thread to execute the tick. This is because the thread may be blocked when the tick needs to happen.

The best you can do is calculate the time till the next tick and reset the duration at the start of the tick event.

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
var nextMinute = now.AddTicks(-(now.Ticks%TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute)).AddMinutes(1);

DispatcherTimer hourTimer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Normal)
{
    Interval = nextMinute - DateTime.UtcNow
};
hourTimer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
{
    var correctionNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var timeCorrection = correctionNow.AddTicks(-(correctionNow.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute)).AddMinutes(1);

    hourTimer.Interval = timeCorrection - DateTime.UtcNow;
    renderTime();
};
hourTimer.Start();
```

Comment: Scott I tried your approach and get "TimeSpan period must be greater than or equal to zero" exception in hourTimer.Interval = timeCorrection - DateTime.UtcNow;. Wont be always DateTime.UtcNow greater than timeCorrection?

Comment: Rounding errors due to `AddMinutes` taking in a `double` may cause the issue. I think what was happening was `AddMinutes` was causing the time to be just a few `Tick`s short of being the next minute so when it truncated the time it set it back to the same starting time. Try my updated version of calculating the next minute, I truncate the seconds ***then*** I add one minute to the time.

Comment: Impresive, it ticks at the exact moment the minute component changes now. Thanks.